# Changing WAMP root folder with special character in path to folder

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to change WAMP directory but in my path there is one word (comupter name) with special character `š`, so when I change dir and restart wamp it stays yellow... I am sure it is because of that because when I use some other path (without special char) it works just fine.
How can I change WAMP root dir to be that path?
Full path : `C:\Users\Dušan\Dropbox`

Answer (score 2):

This may be difficult. As you need to make Apache, MySQL, and PHP all work with this special path... On windows.

And I'm honestly unsure if this won't cause major problems.

My advice is to crate a SHORTCUT folder (like ln -sf on linux), and link it to your destination. You can then install there and work directly on your sites.

Apache conf and mysql, etc. would see a normal path name.

God only knows how the UTF-8 path conversion works between linux and windows ports of these products.

Again, I'd try a standard folder C:\wamp, linked to your www or whichever directory via a shortcut.

Comment: I like your try of fooling WAMP, but bastard is "smart". Still have same results - yellow wamp.

Comment: Are you sure Skype isn't running? Skype binds (steals) port 80. This will cause WAMP to not start. You can disable the port 80 listen in the skype options... Just a thought.